# Pass a Dictionary<string,string> parameter in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass a `Dictionary<string,string>` object as a parameter to my web api method but if I inspect the log file it always comes through with a count of 0:

**Web api method:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("SendPost")]
public void SendPost([FromBody] Dictionary<string,string> values)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter("F:\\PostTest.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Number of items in the dictionary - " + values.Count);
    }
}
```

**Logic which calls the web api:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Send(string uri, string value)
{
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URI);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent
            (
                new Dictionary<string, string> { { "value", value } }
            );

        responseMessage = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
    }
    return responseMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with the fact that you're saying the content-type is "application/json", yet you pass it as `FormUrlEncodedContent`. You need to either use `StringContent` and serialize the content to JSON yourself, or you can use the extention method [`HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx) which serializes the content to JSON for you:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(string uri, string value)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URI);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, content);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed my method to use PostAsJsonAsync but it's still saying the dictionary count in the log file is 0.Should I also change how I'm passing through the content in my example?

Comment: @DenisWessels Did you use the code I posted? Or did you modify yours?

Comment: Sorry I'm being silly, I read your explanation properly and changed my logic to use PostAsJsonAsync and pass through the dictionary directly without creating FormUrlEncodedContent.Now it's working!

Comment: @DenisWessels Great :)