# How do I send a dictionary via Web API?

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a `Dictionary<string,string> filterDictionary`. The dictionary has different key, value filters. I want to pass this to restful webapi as a parameter. Once I pass it to the API, I don't know if Serialization would be good idea? If yes, then what would be the best way to serialize a dictionary? On the other end of the API i need to reconvert the values back to a Dictionary and do my calculations/logic.

```
 var serializeobject= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filterDictionary);
```

Using Newtonsoft library. Is this a right way of doing it?

So two things:

1: How do I send a dictionary via Web API

2: How do I serialize it and then reconvert it back to the dictionary on the other end of API.

Comment: FYI: Dictionaries tend to not support serialization in .NET. I've worked around it by explicitly sending an IEnumerable of a custom KeyValue class

Comment: This has been asked + answered multiple times on this website already. Did you search?

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627370/pass-a-dictionarystring-string-parameter-in-web-api

Comment: var serializeobject= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filterDictionary) is this a right way of doing it?